# Perl: How to remove semicolons from csv

Tags: perl

I have a file and in the Output CSV in one of the cells it’s separating the numbers by semicolon

## |Page Numbers|

|405;349;568;679|

How can I remove the semicolons and separate these numbers into different cells

|405|349|568|678|

|405| header would be page numbers and the other numbers would be the in cells horizontal to each other

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution operator is `s///`. Your specific example can be handled by the following one liner:

```
echo "|405;349;568;679|" | perl -ne 's/;/|/g; print'
```

Implicitly, the `-n` option loops through all the lines piped in, or all the lines in an input file listed afterwards (i.e. The following works too: `perl -ne 's/;/|/g; print' <(echo "|405;349;568;679|")`). Each line is assigned to the variable `$_`. `s/;/|/g` is shorthand for `$_ =~ s/;/|/g`, which replaces all occurrences of `;` with `|`, and `print` without an argument is the same as `print $_`.

It would probably be more straightforward to just use `sed` with the same `g` switch if you want to edit a file.